# CAKeyframeAnimation repeat after a delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, cakeyframeanimation

I have 3 uiviews which have a CAKeyframeAnimation layer added to them to bounce. Currently i add these to each uiview after a delay and set them to repeat.

What i need them to do is repeat but after a delay. so view 1 animates, but waits till after view 2 and 3 have animated before starting again.

I can't seem to read anywhere in the docs that mention repeating a CAKeyframeAnimation with a repeat start time delay.

Can anyone think of an idea to get the delays between the views?

Thanks

Dan

Code so far:

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)jumpAnimation
 {
// these three values are subject to experimentation
CGFloat initialMomentum = 80.0f; // positive is upwards, per sec
CGFloat gravityConstant = 250.0f; // downwards pull per sec
CGFloat dampeningFactorPerBounce = 0.6;  // percent of rebound

// internal values for the calculation
CGFloat momentum = initialMomentum; // momentum starts with initial value
CGFloat positionOffset = 0; // we begin at the original position
CGFloat slicesPerSecond = 60.0f; // how many values per second to calculate
CGFloat lowerMomentumCutoff = 5.0f; // below this upward momentum animation ends

CGFloat duration = 0;
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

do 
{
    duration += 1.0f/slicesPerSecond;
    positionOffset+=momentum/slicesPerSecond;

    if (positionOffset<0)
    {
        positionOffset=0;
        momentum=-momentum*dampeningFactorPerBounce;
    }

    // gravity pulls the momentum down
    momentum -= gravityConstant/slicesPerSecond;

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -positionOffset, 0);
    [values addObject:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
} while (!(positionOffset==0 && momentum < lowerMomentumCutoff));


CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.duration = duration;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.values = values;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
animation.delegate =self;
animation.autoreverses = YES;

return animation;
```

}